# R as.Date() returns NA consistently

Tags: r

I'm using the John Hopkin's COVID-19 dataset which can be found here: https://data.humdata.org/dataset/novel-coronavirus-2019-ncov-cases
namely, the `Corona Confirmed Cases Narrow, the Corona Confirmed Deaths Narrow, and the Corona Confirmed Recovered Narrow`

I'm trying to convert the `Date` column to the `Date` class using `as.Date` but failing. All dates are `NA` no matter what I try. I've tried the following -
converting my locale,
using `stringAsFactors = False` when reading the csv file,
changing the formats constantly.

dates are formatted as `/m/d/Y/`
Before running my code, output of `head(recovered_data$Date)` is:
`[6] 2020-04-06 2020-04-05 2020-04-04 2020-04-03 2020-04-02`

ommitted plenty
after:
`[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA`

I've tried changing the format to be `m-d-Y` but it still doesn't work.

My code:

`recovered_data$Date <- as.Date(as.character(recovered_data$Date),"%d%m%Y")
death_data$Date <- as.Date(as.character(death_data$Date),"%m/%d/%Y")
confirmed_data$Date <- as.Date(as.character(confirmed_data$Date),"%d%m%Y")`

All dates are NA when I access them. Looking at the dataset, it shouldn't be this way.
Thanks!

Comment: please include in your question which dates are failing to process

Comment: @MichaelChirico all of the dates in the dataset. I'll edit with an example

Comment: Show output of `head(recovered_data$Date)`

Comment: there are different datasets, you should specify which one. And I see no date columns in time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv for example

Comment: Clarified everything. Thank you for the comments!

Comment: Yah, I think you want one of the datasets that's been converted to a "narrow" format, not one where each date is a column. In your last edit it looks like that is what you've got, so there isn't a "date" column.

Comment: From memory, that website changed their data format from long format to wide format at the beginning of this month.

Comment: @mock_blatt what do you mean? When I open the csv file, i can see a date column

Comment: @Omri.B so the format is `%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: @Edward I can't belive it, it works! I've read the documentation and it said that if no format is given, It will try default ones until the first non- `NA` appears. any idea why it hasn't happened here?

Comment: You may want to look into my [`anytime` package](http://cloud.r-project.org/package=anytime) whose `anydate()` function may do the conversion automagically for you.  Michael Kane uses it in [this Covid dashboard](https://kaneplusplus.github.io/coronascope/).

Comment: @Omri.B. `as.Date(as.character(recovered_data$Date))` should work, with no "format" argument specified, given what information you've provided. Maybe you could show how you imported the data.

Comment: @Omri.B you might also want to look at *lubridate* package. It has functions of ymd, mdy, dmy, ymd_hms, etc. The naming helps you to easier understand what you are putting in your code.